# How to create list and assign it to variable?

Tags: expl3, comma-separated-list, token-lists

I need to create a comma (or any other) separated list of words for further usage and assign it to variable (macro). The words in list should be placed in separate lines. When I use for this purposes `\def` of `\newcommand` it is necessary to add percent sign `%` to the end of lines.

How can one avoid usage the `%` sign?

My idea, is to create list with expl3:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{ m m}
{
  \tl_set:Nx \l_ty_tl {#1}
  \csc_new:nn {#2}{\tl_use:N \l_ty_tl}

}
```

and use it like

```
\makelist{
Elstat, 
Magstat, 
Current
}{\mylist}

\multiinclude{\mylist}
```

An MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\multiinclude}{ mO{} }
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_ty_tl {#2}
  %\clist_map_inline:Nn #1 { \include{##1\l_ty_tl}} <= real usage
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1 { ##1\l_ty_tl} %<= for MWE
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand\mylist{%
Elstat,% 
Magstat,% 
Current}
\chapter{Problems}
\multiinclude{\mylist}[]

\chapter{Answers}
\multiinclude{\mylist}[-AnswersFile]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to “normalize” the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\multiinclude}{ mO{} }
 {
  \clist_set:Nx \l_sergio_mi_clist { #1 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_sergio_mi_clist { \noindent ##1 #2 \par }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand\mylist{
  Elstat,
  Magstat,
  Current
}

\section{Problems}
\multiinclude{\mylist}[]

\section{Answers}
\multiinclude{\mylist}[-AnswersFile]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I'd avoid `\newcommand` and call lists by name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\multiinclude}{ m O{} }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { l_sergio_list_#1_clist } { \noindent ##1 #2 \par }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{ mm }
 {
  \clist_set:cn { l_sergio_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makelist{mylist}{
  Elstat,
  Magstat, 
  Current
}

\section{Problems}
\multiinclude{mylist}[]

\section{Answers}
\multiinclude{mylist}[-AnswersFile]

\end{document}
```